# Can my wife leave the UK while on a spouse visa?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, spouses

I'm recently married. I was born here in the UK. My wife lives with me and has an Indian passport and spouse visa. We are looking at going on holiday back to India. Is she allowed to leave the country and return back with me freely?

I'm confused. Some people said if she left she may not be allowed to re-enter the UK.

Comment: Technically it is true.  Anyone who is not a British citizen can be denied entry for certain reasons.  However holders of spouse visas, and other "settled" immigrants, for that matter, will not be denied entry unless there is evidence of fraud or other criminality.

Comment: To be sure, is this a "family of a settled person" visa?

Comment: Congratulations on your wedding.

Answer (score 4):

The visa that your wife has should have a valid up to date printed on it and as long as she returns before the expiry of that visa she is fine. Once that visa expires she would need to get a Leave to remain indefinitely in the UK from East Croyden (Home office), they will ask for proof of you two living together like mobile phone bills for both of you and bank statements with same address printed on them as proof.